# apache .htaccess rewritecond problems catching all admin requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to get my .htaccess conditions to work, but they don't seem to be working correctly, specifically the 2nd group where I'm removing the /admin/ directory - it keeps getting caught in the 1st group conditions

```
# If the request is either /admin/ or /admin/index.html, rewrite to just admin.html
# http://foo.com/admin/
# http://foo.com/admin/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^ admin.html [L]

# if the request starts w/ /admin/, then remove the /admin folder and continue processing
# http://foo.com/admin/bar/baz.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/.*$
RewriteRule ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1

# if any resource is not a directory or file, then rewrite to the index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Here is a mapping how it should all work

`group one`

- http://foo.com/admin  -> http://foo.com/admin.html
- http://foo.com/admin/index.html -> http://foo.com/admin.html

`group two`

- http://foo.com/admin/bar/baz.css -> http://foo.com/bar/baz.css
- http://foo.com/admin/baz.css -> http://foo.com/baz.css

`group three`

- http://foo.com/bar/baz.css -> http://foo.com/bar/baz.css (assuming /bar/baz.css exists)
- http://foo.com/bar/baz.css -> http://foo.com/index.html (assuming /bar/baz.css doesn't exist)

Answer (score -1):

Why not eliminate the first set of rules and let the second set handle all of the admin redirects. Then in Apache set admin.html to the default document?